# Navigation menu not working properly In IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 whenever I click on any navigation menu the menus got overlapped with each other...It works fine with other browser.
Here the link of my site :http://eassignments.in

Here is code of navigatio menu:=

```
li id="<?php echo ($epage =='ehome') ? 'current' : ''?>"  ><a href="home.php?epage=ehome">Home</a></li><?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
    <li id="<?php echo ($epage =='Home') ? 'current' : ''?>"  ><a href="index.php?epage=Home">Home</a></li><?php
    }
?>
<li ><a href="">Registration</a>
<ul class="nav1 first"><li   id="<?php echo ($epage =='creg') ? 'current' : ''?>" ><a href="creg.php?epage=creg">Candidate Registration</a></li>
<li  id="<?php echo ($epage =='ereg') ? 'current' : ''?>" ><a  href="Empyr.php?epage=ereg">Employer Registration</a></li></ul>
</li><?php
?><li id="<?php echo ($epage =='search_a') ? 'current' : ''?>" ><a href="asearch.php?epage=search_a" >Search Assignment</a></li><?php
?><li id="<?php echo ($epage =='carticle') ? 'current' : ''?>" ><a href="article.php?epage=carticle">articleship</a></li><?php
?><li id="<?php echo ($epage=='contact') ? 'current' : ''?>" ><a href="contact.php?epage=contact">Contact Us</a></li><?php 

}
?>
```

CSS Code:

```
 #nav, .nav, #nav .nav li { margin:0px; padding:0px; }
#nav li {float:left; display:inline; cursor:pointer; list-style:none; padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; border:1px #000 solid; position:relative;}
#nav li ul.first {left:-1px; top:100%;}

li, li a {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
#nav .nav li { width:100%; text-indent:10px; line-height:30px; margin-right:10px; border-top:1px #000 solid; border-bottom:1px #000 solid; 
border-left:none; border-right:none; background:#fff;}
#nav li a {display:block; width:inherit; height:inherit;}

ul.nav { display:none; }
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover { color:#fff; background:#000; }
li:hover > .nav { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; top:-2px; left:50%; z-index:1000; border:1px #000 solid; } 
li:hover { position:relative; z-index:2000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be working, try to restart the browser and if still does not work re-install the browser.

Comment: i have tried re-installing the browser,but the problem is still there.